# control ansible task file execution

Tags: ansible

My current Ansible project is setup like so:

```
backup-gitlab.yml
roles/
   aws_backups/
      tasks/
         main.yml
         backup-vm.yml
   gitlab/
      tasks/
         main.yml
         start.yml
         stop.yml
```

`backup-gitlab.yml` needs to do the following:

1. Invoke `stop.yml` on the gitlab host.
2. Invoke `backup-gitlab.yml` on a different host.
3. Invoke `start.yml` on the gitlab host.

The problem I'm running into is Ansible doesn't seem to support a way of choosing which task files to run within the same role in the same playbook.  Before I was using tags to control what Ansible would do, but in this case tagging the include statements for `start.yml` and `stop.yml` doesn't work because Ansible doesn't appear to have a way to dynamically change the applied tags that are run once they are set through the command line.

I can't come up with an elegant way to achieve this.

Some options are:

1. Have each task file be contained within its own role.  This is annoying because I will end up with a million roles that are not grouped in any way.  It's essentially abandoning the whole 'role' concept.
2. Use `include` with hard coded paths.  This is prone to error as things move around.  Also, since Ansible deprecated combining `with_items` with `include` (or using any sort of dynamic looping with `include`), I can no longer quickly change up the task files being run.  Any minor change in my workflow requires lots of coding changes.  I would really like to stick with using tags from the command line to control exactly what Ansible does.
3. Use shell scripts to invoke separate Ansible playbooks.
4. Use conditionals (`when` clause) on every single Ansible `action`, and control what gets run by setting variables.  While several people have recommended this on SO, it sounds awful.  I will have to add the conditional to hundreds of actions and every time I run a playbook the output will be cluttered by hundred's of 'skip' statements.
5. Leverage Jinja templates and ansible's `local_connection` to dynamically build static `main.yml` files with all the required task files included in the proper order (using computed relative paths).  Then invoke that computed `main.yml` file.  This is dangerous and convoluted.
6. Use top level Ansible plays to invoke lower level plays.  Seems messy, also this brings in problems when I need to pass variables between plays.  Using Ansible's Python Api may help this.

Ansible strives to bring VMs into idempotent states but this isn't very helpful and is a dated way of thinking in my opinion (I would have stuck with Chef if that is all I wanted).  I want to leverage Ansible to actually do things such as: actively change configuration states, kick off processes, monitor events, react to events, etc.  Essentially I want it to automate as much of my job as possible.  The current 'role' structure (with static configurations) that Ansible recommends doesn't fit this paradigm very well even though their usage of remote command execution via SSH gets us so close to the dream.

Comment: Have you looked at https://docs.ansible.com/playbooks_delegation.html#delegation ?

Comment: I wonder if multiple hosts can be specified for delegates.  If so, it will provide a much more dynamic way of specifying where to run tasks rather then setting a static host within the play.  I think in this case it would be a cleaner alternative to option #2, but I'd still be required to add a new line for every single task.  I think breaking the roles up into a single role for each task is the best solution.  My usage of Ansible doesn't fit the 'role' paradigm since I'm dynamically changing the state of managed applications so I shouldn't be trying to bundle multiple tasks into a single role

Answer (score 0):

Just use a playbook for these types of management tasks.

Granted the skip statements do somewhat clutter the output. If you wish to fix that you can further breakdown the roles into something like  `aws_backups-setup` and `aws_backups-managment`.

Also the [roles documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_roles.html#roles) has some information on how you can run `pre_tasks` and `post_tasks` on roles.